# Vectorize code in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization

How to vectorize this code in MATLAB?

```
n = 3;
x = zeros(n);
y = x;
for i = 1:n
  x(:,i) = i;
  y(i,:) = i;
end
```

I am not able to vectorize it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n=3;
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:n);
```

This uses [`meshgrid`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) which does this automatically.

Or you can use [`bsxfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) as [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar) suggests:

```
bsxfun(@plus,1:n,zeros(n,1))
```

Just as a note on your initial looped code: it's bad practise to [use `i` as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Comment: I suggest a fight to the death with @Benoit_11;)

Comment: Or use `bsxfun` ;) `bsxfun(@plus,1:n,zeros(n,1))` and its transpose.

Comment: @Divakar I should've thought of that :( I just ran his code and saw it exactly matched `meshgrid`'s output, so I didn't stop to think about the great `bsxfun`. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Careful with the `n` though. You are using it as a vector with `meshgrid` and as a scalar with `bsxfun`. Since OP is using `n = 3;`, sticking to that might make sense.

Comment: I'm on the verge of making the answer community-wiki since you added more than I did here ;) @Divakar

Comment: `meshgrid` would be the go-to approach here for efficiency and all that. `bsxfun` one is just for people bored of usual ways, so it's all good I think.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `meshgrid` :

```
n = 3;
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:n,1:n)

x =

     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     1     2     3


y =

     1     1     1
     2     2     2
     3     3     3
```

Answer (score 2):

If I can add something to the mix, create a row vector from `1` to `n`, then use [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) on this vector to create `x`.  After, transpose `x` to get `y`:

```
n = 3;
x = repmat(1:n, n, 1);
y = x.';
```

Running this code, we get:

```
>> x

x =

     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     1     2     3

>> y

y =

     1     1     1
     2     2     2
     3     3     3
```